# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar esta función?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Cl() {
  this.copas = 2;
  this.nombre = 'Chile';
  var privada = function(e) {
    return e * 2;
  };
}
    
var a = new Cl();
a.privada();
```

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar la *expresión función privada* desde fuera, que está dentro del constructor? Apunto a obtener una explicación con documentación.

Porque quiero saber si es posible ejecutar la función privada fuera, o es simplemente imposible, y sin el uso de otra función pública para acceder a la privada.

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres hacer. ¿Por qué no haces `this.privada` como con las otras propiedades?

Comment: por que quiero saber si es posible de alguna forma, ejecutar la funcion privada fuera, o es simplemente imposible? y sin el uso de otra funcion publica para acceder a la privada

Comment: Teóricamente una función privada no debería ser accesible desde fuera, lo que quieres hacer parece ir en contra de la definición y ámbito de las variables/métodos (tu función privada ya no sería privada.)

Comment: entonces no se puede? podrias hacer una respuesta entonces por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera que tienes de ejecutar la función `privada` desde fuera es guardándola en un atributo de cada objeto instanciado usando `this`:

```js
function Cl() {
  this.copas = 2;
  this.nombre = 'Chile';
  this.privada = function(e) {
    return e * 2;
  };
}

var a = new Cl();
console.log(a.privada(10));
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es mantener la función `privada` como privada internamente dentro del constructor y que no pueda ser accedida desde fuera, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function Cl() {
  this.copas = 2;
  this.nombre = 'Chile';
  var privada = function(e) {
    return e * 2;
  };
  this.publica = function(e) {
    return privada(e);
  }
}

var a = new Cl();
console.log(a.publica(10));   // No hay manera de acceder a la función privada desde fuera, salvo llamando a la función publica y que esta acceda a privada.
```

Haciéndolo de esta manera, `privada` es una variable temporal (apuntando a una función) que desaparece al finalizar la llamada a la función `Cl`. Pero, como dentro de esa llamada a `Cl` se crea otra función que se guarda en el atributo `publica` del objeto instanciado, la definición de dicha función `publica` está dentro del contexto o entorno interno de la función constructor `Cl`. De esta manera, el contexto interno de `Cl` (variables locales creadas) no desparece para la función `publica` aun habiendo finalizado la ejecución del constructor `Cl`, así que la variable con la función `privada` estará siempre disponible para `publica` pero sólo podrá ser accedida fuera de `Cl` desde dentro del método `publica` del objeto instanciado. Es una manera equivalente de crear un método privado.